# Java Do While loop skipping condition

Tags: java, debugging, loops, do-while

I have a do while loop that is terminating without the condition being met and I'm not sure why. When I debug check's row and columns are (4,10) and goal's are (4,1). Any ideas?

```
Position check = unexplored.get();
do{

    if(isValid(check.up())){                       
        unexplored.put(check.up());
        numUnexplored++;
    }
    if(isValid(check.right())){
        unexplored.put(check.right());
        numUnexplored++;
    }
    if(isValid(check.down())){
        unexplored.put(check.down());
        numUnexplored++;
        }
    if(isValid(check.left())){
        unexplored.put(check.left());
        numUnexplored++;
        }
    explore(check);
    explored.put(check);
    check = unexplored.get(); 

 }while(check.getColumn() != goal.getColumn() && check.getRow() != goal.getRow());
```

It's worth noting that if I change checks initialization at the top to:

```
Position check = null;
```

and then set it at the top of the loop, like:

```
do{
    check = unexplored.get();
    ....
```

the loop terminates at the same spot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to exit only when `check` and `goal` refer to the same cell, then you'll need to change `&&` to `||` in your `while` condition.

Comment: Isn't that OR? Wouldn't that terminate if `check` and `goal`s columns OR rows were the same but not both?

Comment: You want it to continue if it's a different row OR a different column.